# Conditional in jsx return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Pretty new to React, and I'm sure this is easy, but I'm trying to convert this:

```
    return values.map(value => {
        if(head) return <th key={uuidv4()}> {value} </th>;
        return <td key={uuidv4()}> {value} </td>
    });
```

into a single return statement.

Basically a conditional check that replaces the `<th>` tags with a `<td>`. In vanilla I'd just return a template string, but I can't seem to get this to work with jsx. (Something like this) `<${head? 'th': 'td'} key=${uuidv4()}>${value}</${head? 'th': 'td'}>`

I feel like I'm close, but I'm obviously returning a string ::shrug::

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Yes it does, thanks - I did try to search but didn't think to call it a dynamic tag. Strange that it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
return values.map(value => {
  const Tag = `h${head ? 'th' : 'td'}`;
  return <Tag key={uuidv4()}>{value}</Tag>
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely like this approach, even though it's not a single line

Comment: Out of interest - I changed the flag to a string and tried to put it directly as the tag itself, ie: `<tag key={uuidv4()}>{value}</tag>` - but it only works when assigned with a captial letter as you've done. Not quite sure why?

Comment: It's a convention for React : Uppercase = function/component, otherwise it's an html element.

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
return values.map(value => {
    return head ? <th key={uuidv4()}> {value} </th> :
                  <td key={uuidv4()}> {value} </td>
});
```

It is important to say: The "duplication" of code in the 2 options (td or th) is in my opinion **great!** because these are two different types of UI features you have. It is better to keep them separated and keep it possible to put changes in each one of them alone.

Comment: yeah, I guess it's just bugging me that I can' seem to work out how to replace parts of the statement, but thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome, please notice the edit for the answer about the code structure.